# mysql comparing two tables then insert into a new one

Tags: mysql

i have two identical table. i want to compare these two table and getting the result from them. the condition are

1. each record in TABLE1 **grouped by TID** will be compared to all records in TABLE2 **grouped by their each TID**..
2. if each **grouped** record in TABLE1 are to be discovered in TABLE2 (records in TABLE2 that grouped by each tid, too), as many as N (N is the user input variable), then that record will be inserted into new table

for example like the ss below, **ITEM C-F-A** grouped by **TID 2** has 3 occurences in table2, thus they will be inserted into new table

[image]

i've already tried writing the code for this and it worked( vb.net), but the compiler takes ridicoulous time to complete. The main cause is i'm proccessing a huge database

the method i've done in program is populate the two table into 2d array. assigning value to array while comparing the two element with `if clause`..

below is the 2d array that i've created
[image]

but this method is really expensive, **my real database on pic above is 1st 2d array has 2k records and 2nd 2d array has 800 records**. and when i try to calculate the estimate time for compiling to completed. it showed a fantastic number, about 16 hours.. gosh!!

so i wondering, whether this problem can be solved with mysql query?

or other method that more effective than i have done